# Displaying the commit tree in github?

Tags: github

A simple question, but one I can't figure out for myself:

Is there a way to persuade github --- *not* the git command line tool! --- to show me a graphical view of the commit tree rather than a flat list of commits?

Comment: have you tried http://gitup.co or sourcetree?

Comment: I want to know whether github does this, not an external tool.

Comment: github web interface does not provide what you want. you need external tools or services anyway

Comment: GitLab can do this.  On a GitLab project page, navigate to Repository -> Graph.

Answer (score 26):

In the main page of the repository, click Insights -> click Network.

Comment: Shame it's pro-only

Comment: Seems like it's now free, not pro-only anymore

Answer (score 5):

In GitHub there's a path `/commits` to see the a sequential list of commits leading up to a given commit or a branch. It presents it in a form of a **timeline**. It's accessible as `History` link.

For example,
link

- show the current timeline for `main` branch: `<repository-path>/commits/main`
- the timeline leading to a given commit SHA: `<repository-path>/commits/SHA`

The resulting timeline allows paging into the older history, each commit could be clicked for details.

This does not show a graph of branches (as shown in `Insights/Network`), rather it's a timeline for a given branch/line of descent.

Comment: this was helpful to view the commit history for a SHA that was not in a branch (or from a deleted branch).

Answer (score 2):

You can view a graphical representation in the Network tab on the Graphs page.

Comment: @DavidGiven: It also shows branches for each repo (and, of course, where they branched and where they are merged).

Comment: Well, git --graph --all is showing me plenty of branches which aren't showing up there.

Comment: @DavidGiven: Have they been pushed to GitHub?

Comment: Yes, they have been pushed to github.

Comment: @DavidGiven: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @DavidGiven: That repo only has two branches, master and gh-pages; both are shown on the Network tab.

Comment: Then we're talking about about different things; git --graph --all shows a bunch of branching and merging. It's this view I want.

Comment: @DavidGiven: The Network tab basically does that; it's the closest you're going to get on GitHub, at least. (I don't believe it shows tags, but it shows all branches.)

Comment: @DavidGiven: In the example you gave, the Network tab shows a visualization of branching and merging, although the example repo you linked only has two branches (and they happen to be independent branches with no shared history). I'm not sure what you expect to see in that case.